# Print layer shifting on Alunar M508 Prusa i3 clone

Tags: troubleshooting, y-axis, print-failure

[Edit: My specific question is firmware error or standard layer shifting. using 2 different versions of Cura were getting quite different results from the same stl file.]

Per the image below with Cura 15.4 the centered print both shifted to the bottom of the print bed for the first few passes and then did not build the proper internal structure of the bracket. the top loops were then skewed to the top of the bed.  The 2<sup>nd</sup> print in the corner was using Cura 3.1 and the first few passes like usual skewed off towards the bottom but it seemed to start printing normally after that.  I am trying to determine if it is a hardware calibration issue or bad firmware on the printer. Any suggestions on what's going on would be appreciated. For some reason the image flipped 180° when posting.

Center part completed its print and should be about an inch or so tall. It was not even able to build the internal structure like the 2<sup>nd</sup> one had started to do. the 2<sup>nd</sup> one I stopped after about 10 min since it clearly showed different behavior. from the layer shifting links the most likely cause would be over current stepping.

[image: Failed layer shifting prints]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Y layer shift on Creality Ender 3?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/how-to-fix-y-layer-shift-on-creality-ender-3)

Comment: If I may ask, what's going on with your bed tape? If your settings dictate a 0.1mm layer height, the bubbles we are looking at in your tape are going to mess with your print. By having the rough layers of tape with bubbles and the edges not sticking, you are just creating more issues for yourself. I'm not sure what kind of tape that is, and maybe it just isn't sticking too well. If you must use tape, get some 3M Blue Painter's tape and ensure there's no overlap of the tape, there are no gaps, and most importantly, there's no bubbles.

Comment: That bed tape is very badly mounted. You want to put it down as flat as possible and not overlapping. As you laid it down, the nozzle will catch at the upcurling edges and incuce layer shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect is called [layer shifting](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/#layer-shifting-or-misalignment) . Now that you know what it is called you could look at some other solutions fixing this issue; e.g. [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/how-to-fix-y-layer-shift-on-creality-ender-3), [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/layer-shifting-on-product-printing-after-raft-support-structure) or [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7867/what-causes-this-stringing-and-can-my-print-recover-from-this/7875#7875). The answers of [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/how-to-fix-y-layer-shift-on-creality-ender-3/7700#7700) describe best what is causing this. Usually (most of all the cases) it means that your belts are not tight enough.

An edit of the question shows that the effect happens when a different version of Ultimaker Cura is being used. In such cases you need to check the speeds and acceleration settings. Too high values may lead to skipping steps causing layer shifting. Be sure it is not a mechanical issue, also note that the nozzle does not get caught up by the uneven tape on the bed. In that effect, you may want to look at [this unaswered question](/q/3314/).

Comment: @Kendrick get your print speeds down to at best 150 mm. and Flatten your tape!

Comment: Ended up being a missing set screw for the bed stepper.  it was tight enough to hold during normal movement but when transitioning from the back where the layer ended to the front corner etc the speed would go to high and slip.